# How to re-launch main activity after pressing back to go to home in Android

Tags: java, mobile, launcher

My project has 2 activities- First.java and Second.java

First.java is the launcher activity. I have manually set the `onbackPressed()` for `Second.java` so that when I press the back button from Second.java, it takes the user to home.

When I re-open the application, I am getting Second.java but I want First.java to be displayed again.

I have used this code to go to home:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Activity` class is `First.java` and you're executing code in `Second.java`, this must do the trick:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, First.class);
    finish(); // to simulate "restart" of the activity.
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Also you can check, [`Activity.recreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) if you're using API 11 and beyond.¡

Comment: this isn't exactly what I was looking for, but thanks, I got the hint from your code and it solved a big problem!

Comment: Hi @SheenaGupta I've been looking your profile and notticed **you've not accepted any answer yet**. I would suggest to review [your asked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4646539/sheena-gupta?tab=questions) and it's answers and any answer has solved one of your questions please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course, there is no obligation to do this, but you will contribute to SO quality.

Comment: I have been trying to do it, but it requires minimum 15 reputation and I have only 6.

Comment: You mean `upvote` and `downvote` an answer or question, What I mean is to `mark answer as accepted`, you can do this with any reputation by clicking the checkmark (like `V`) at the side of the answer that fits your needs. **Each time mark a question as answered you will get+2 reputation points**. For sure, don't hesitate to ask if you need more info. ;)